# Issues Linking pcap.p when libpcap is installed on my Ubuntu

Tags: c, linker, pcap

I found a handy [packet capture program in C](http://yuba.stanford.edu/%7Ecasado/pcap/testpcap1.c) and went to compile it on my home Ubuntu box.  The original code had this at the top:

```
#include <pcap/pcap.h>
```

But when I compiled, I saw this:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/me# gcc -Wall packetCap.c
/tmp/cc2kDt1M.o: In function `main':
packetCap.c:(.text+0x33): undefined reference to `pcap_lookupdev'
packetCap.c:(.text+0xa0): undefined reference to `pcap_open_live'
packetCap.c:(.text+0xef): undefined reference to `pcap_next'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
root@ubuntu:/home/me#
```

Doesn’t look like the code can see pcap.h.  I did a search, found what appears to be a fully-working version of pcap.h in `/usr/include/pcap/`, and then changed my code to this:

```
//#include <pcap/pcap.h>                // if this gives you an error try pcap/pcap.h
#include "/usr/include/pcap/pcap.h"
```

But I still got the exact same compilation errors.

Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?  I looked at earlier StackOverflow posts, and here's some basic tricks I did to rule out earlier SO guidance:

First, specifying the directory when compiling had no effect:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/me# gcc -I/usr/include/pcap -Wall packetCap.c
/tmp/cc2kDt1M.o: In function `main':
packetCap.c:(.text+0x33): undefined reference to `pcap_lookupdev'
packetCap.c:(.text+0xa0): undefined reference to `pcap_open_live'
packetCap.c:(.text+0xef): undefined reference to `pcap_next'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
root@ubuntu:/home/me#
```

I grepped `/usr/include/pcap/pcap.h`, and it looks like the functions I need are described within:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/me# more /usr/include/pcap/pcap.h | grep pcap_lookupdev
PCAP_API char   *pcap_lookupdev(char *);
root@ubuntu:/home/me# more /usr/include/pcap/pcap.h | grep pcap_open_live
        char *name;             /* name to hand to "pcap_open_live()" */
PCAP_API pcap_t *pcap_open_live(const char *, int, int, int, char *);
root@ubuntu:/home/me# more /usr/include/pcap/pcap.h | grep pcap_next
PCAP_API const u_char *pcap_next(pcap_t *, struct pcap_pkthdr *);
PCAP_API int    pcap_next_ex(pcap_t *, struct pcap_pkthdr **, const u_char **);
root@ubuntu:/home/me#
```

And I definitely have libpcap installed:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/me# apt-get install libpcap-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libpcap-dev is already the newest version (1.7.4-2ubuntu0.1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libjline-java libnetty-3.9-java libpython-all-dev libpython3-dev libpython3.5-dev libzookeeper-java python-all python-all-dev python-pip-whl python-wheel python3-dev python3-wheel python3.5-dev zookeeper
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 442 not upgraded.
root@ubuntu:/home/me#
```

Do I have to do a `#define PCAP_API` at the stop of my code or something?  Can anyone spot what I’m doing wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: You are _not_ getting a _compile_ error. You are getting a _linker_ error (Note the `ld` in the error message). Add `-lpcap` to the end of the compile line to link with `libpcap`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the pcap library in the link command. The best way to know pcap include paths and libs to link is to use `pcap-config` tool.

```
$ pcap-config --cflags
-I/usr/include
$ pcap-config --libs
-lpcap
```

In the compile command, you could use:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra $(pcap-config --cflags) packetCap.c $(pcap-config --libs)
```

Comment: @P P  - Yes!  You got it exactly right.  I love this forum!!!  thank you